# Programmatically authenticate to Google Compute Engine via service access key

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

After researching the Google Compute Documentation I found out that there is no example of authentication via a generated Service Access Key.

I tried it with the following code (this is line 69)

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(authorize())
                .build();
```

and

```
private static  GoogleClientSecrets authorize() {
    // initialize client secrets object
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets;
    // load client secrets
    try {
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(
                GCEImporter.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


    return clientSecrets;
}
```

the client_secrets.json is the generated file from google which looks like this

```
{
 "type": "service_account",
 "project_id": "...",
 "private_key_id": "...",
 "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
 "client_email": "....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
 "client_id": "...",
 "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
 "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
 "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
 "client_x509_cert_url": 
 "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/..."
}
```

all I receive when executing this code is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setClientSecrets(GoogleCredential.java:559)
at net.bytesource.jira.asset.synchronization.importer.google.gce.GCEImporter.getAssets(GCEImporter.java:69)
at net.bytesource.jira.asset.synchronization.importer.google.gce.GoogleImporterTest.getAssets(GoogleImporterTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Tuxdude.
I also have tried your way in advance by copying the example from the website. But this does only work from within an instance in the GCE environment.

I have found the solution myself which was a static method from GoogleCredential class:

```
GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStreamReader("path/to/json"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here:

- The private key info json file that you downloaded when you created a new service account from the IAM page is not in the [format that is expected by Client Secrets](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets).
- You're trying to follow the `[OAuth steps that are meant for Desktop and mobile apps][2]`. This will not work with Google Cloud APIs.

The recommended and simpler way for authorizing with Google Cloud APIs is to use Application Default Credentials which is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#application_default_credentials) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

In short what you need to do is (based on the outline [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#callingjava)):

1. Set the path to the JSON file you have in the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.
2. Create the `GoogleCredential` object as shown below.

`GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();`

After the above step, you should be able to talk to any of the Google Cloud APIs. In case of GCE, you will create an instance of `Compute`

`Compute compute = new Compute.Builder
    (transport, jsonFactory, credential).build();`

I am just copying and pasting the example from compute.instances.insert API [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert).

```
/*
 * BEFORE RUNNING:
 * ---------------
 * 1. If not already done, enable the Compute Engine API
 *    and check the quota for your project at
 *    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute
 * 2. This sample uses Application Default Credentials for authentication.
 *    If not already done, install the gcloud CLI from
 *    https://cloud.google.com/sdk and run
 *    `gcloud beta auth application-default login`.
 *    For more information, see
 *    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
 * 3. Install the Java client library on Maven or Gradle. Check installation
 *    instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client.
 *    On other build systems, you can add the jar files to your project from
 *    https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/compute/v1/java
 */
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.compute.Compute;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Instance;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Operation;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ComputeExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Project ID for this request.
    String project = ""; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The name of the zone for this request.
    String zone = ""; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // TODO: Assign values to desired fields of `requestBody`:
    Instance requestBody = new Instance();

    Compute computeService = createComputeService();
    Compute.Instances.Insert request =
        computeService.instances().insert(project, zone, requestBody);

    Operation response = request.execute();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static Compute createComputeService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    return new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-ComputeSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```